# Docker: How to source a virtualenv and install requirements.txt?

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. The `canonicaliser_api` contains my code and a `requirements.txt`.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.2
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install python build-essential python-dev python-pip python-setuptools -y
RUN apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-common postgresql-client -y
RUN apt-get install openssl openssl-blacklist openssl-blacklist-extra -y
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
RUN pip install virtualenv uwsgi

ADD canonicaliser_api /home/ubuntu
RUN virtualenv /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv
RUN source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80

CMD service nginx start
```

When I'm trying to build it, everything is fine until step 11:

```
Step 11 : RUN source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 7aae5bd92b70
/home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt'
The command '/bin/sh -c source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

But this makes no sense, I have added the the whole code directory in Dockerfile via the `ADD`. Am I missing here something?

```
bash-3.2$ ls canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt 
canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Usage is: ADD [source directory or URL] [destination directory]

You need to add the folder name to the destination:

```
ADD canonicaliser_api /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when copying directories, especially when the destination directory doesn't exist. In short, this won't work:

```
ADD canonicaliser_api /home/ubuntu
```

But this should:

```
ADD canonicaliser_api /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
```

In general, it's better to avoid the `ADD` instruction and use `COPY` instead. In this case, it's just a direct replacement.

In future, a way to debug things like this is to take the last image that was successfully built (in this  case, the one from the `ADD` line) and start a container from it. Then you can try running the problematic instruction and figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm afraid, its no solution. I still experience the same problem. Let me try COPY instead. Same problem with COPY. :(

Comment: Ah, got it. It's even more confusing as `/home/ubuntu` doesn't exist

Comment: Ha, just noticed someone answered in between edits (for the record I originally suggested adding a `/` which makes no difference).  I'll leave the updated answer as I think the other points are still valid.